# parametr's from mysql_fetch_assoc() don't want to displays ;

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i can't understand why echo don't displays value. Query return values in phpmyadmin sow query is fine. Please help

```
$query="SELECT `doctor_name` , `doctor_secondname` 
FROM `doctors`
INNER JOIN `patients` ON `patients`.doctor_id = `doctors`.doctor_id 
WHERE `patients`.patient_id = '{.$patient_id.}'" ;

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

print_r($row);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
$row    = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "Your doctor is :";
echo $row['doctor_name'];
echo $row['doctor_secondname'];
   }
```

Comment: This `'{.$patient_id.}'` is wrong.

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` functionality. You should move to `msqli` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$query="SELECT doctor_name , doctor_secondname 
FROM doctors
INNER JOIN patients ON patients.doctor_id = doctors.doctor_id 
WHERE patients.patient_id = '".$patient_id."'" ;
```